# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Я устал, помогите, пожалуйста.
У меня на локалхосте я делаю ajax запрос на php сервер, мой js проверял во вкладке, отправляет данные точно, но принять ответ от сервера я не могу, тк ответа по какой-то причине нет.(ниже показываю, что не могу отправить с сервера даже статичные данные).

```
//php server
$arrayRes = ["nya","nya","nya",];
if (isset($_POST["hidden"])) {
echo $arrayRes;
}

//js 
let response = await fetch('/store.php', {
      method: "POST",
      body: new FormData(form),
    });

    let userComment = await response.json();
```

----------------- 500 internal server error
исходные файлы:

```
///store.php
```

Прошу,я уже отчаялся я очень и очень много времени потратил на это но так и не смог пофиксить, хотя изначально статичные данные отправлять получалось. Добавил чуть кода и всё нафиг поломалось, как думаете, что не так?

[image: backend]

Comment: Непонятно, что конкретно Вы пытаетесь сделать и почему предоставили именно эти данные. Подскажите, что Вы подразумеваете под `PHP сервер`? У Вас есть сервер, на котором Вы установили `php`, так? Или же стоит просто `php` стоит у Вас локально? Если отдельный сервер, то Вы явно не корректно передаёте данные, если же локально, что предполагается под `/store.php`, то каким образом Вы получаете данные? Скорее всего Вы просто через форму передавали данные в `php`, а не через `fetch`. Если есть необходимость - могу написать пример передачи данных через `fetch`.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Напишите мне интересно) по-моему он ещё должен в `$_POST['hidden']` передать данные... Интересно как это делается через `fetch`

Comment: @Denis640Kb, под сервером я имел в виду локальный.
Смысл в том, что я каким-то образом поломал работающий свой же скрипт и потратил весь день, но не смог его пофиксить, я отправляю Post на свой php, а он не может ответить должным образом, то есть в Ajax приходить что-то типо null, эти статичные данные я вставил уже тк нет сил и таким образом я тестил, выводит ли вообще что-нибудь php в ответ, оказалось нет, друзья, добавляйтесь ко мне на профиль, я ток зарегался, пока дорублюсь что да как, оч нуждаюсь в общении

Comment: @DmitriySaxarov Добавил информацию ;)

Answer (score 2):

Во первых `echo $arrayRes;` это уже не верно, так как `echo` выводит строки на экран, а `$arrayRes` это массив, а не строка, для вывода массива используйте `print_r`. Во вторых массив, который может быть преобразован в `JSON`, должен быть ассоциативным, например

```
$arrayRes = array(["key" => "value", "key" => "nya"]),
```

хотя можно и обычный массив преобразовать, тогда ключи будут нумероваться с 0 и т.д. В третьих чтобы вывести массив в виде `JSON` строки нужно использовать функцию [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) примерно так `echo(json_encode($arrayRes, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));`. Если хотите могу полный пример написать, только с использованием jQuery `$.ajax`, а не `await fetch`, так как даже не знаю что это)

Comment: Господи, какой прекрасный ресурс, мне самоучке так не хватает общения с людьми по интересу)
ну можно на query, я его понимаю, не принципиально)
>хотя можно и обычный массив преобразовать, тогда ключи будут нумероваться с 0 и т.д.
Да, у меня сначала так и работала и я был доволен, пока не поломал всё.

Comment: >> echo выводит строки на экран, а $arrayRes это массив, а не строка, для вывода массива используйте print_r 
Про это постоянно забываю, мне нужно в выходной поток кинуть массив, получается, echo не сработает? Можете ко мне на комп зайти через teamViewer на пару минут?) https://vk.com/amikawa

Comment: print_r не решил проблему, от сервера приходит 500 status code

Answer (score 2):

Как уже корректно Вам сообщил Dmitriy Saxarov, `echo` выводит содержимое строк.
Подробнее Вы можете почитать [Про echo](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php)
Для того, чтобы вывести массив для отображения, Вам необходимо использовать `print_r($arrayRes);` или `var_dump`
Они смогут вывести для Вас информацию в формате массива (Просто для отображения).
Чуть больше информации о `print_r` и `var_dump` Вы можете почитать [Тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.print-r.php)
В случае, когда Вы хотите передать данные через `fetch`, Вам в первую очередь необходимо набрать информационную базу о том, что же такое он собой представляет и каким образом работает. 
Согласитесь, что когда понимаешь, как именно работает тот или иной код - гораздо проще становится использовать его в дальнейшем. 
Подробнее про [Fetch](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch) Вы можете почитать по ссылке.

Ниже указан рабочий код по использованию передачи данных из формы в файл `php` при помощи `fetch`
Первый файл:

```php
<?php
?>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="123">
    <button formmethod="post">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    const form = document.querySelector('form'); // в js получаем параметры данных в form
    form.addEventListener('submit', evt => { // Отслеживаем нажатие кнопки, чтобы выполнить наши действия. (Необходимо уточнить, что отслеживать можно разные события, для большей информации почитайте про `addEventListener` в `javascript`
        evt.preventDefault(); // Убираем автоматическую отправку формы `submit`
        fetch('form.php', { // инициируем отправку формы данных в файл `form.php`
            method: 'POST', // Указываем метод отправки данных
            body: new FormData(form) // Формируем форму в тело отправляемых данных
        }).then(function(response){ // Then указывает последовательность действий, в данном случае ожидание получения ответа от скрипта из файла `form.php`
        console.log(response) // Выводим данные в консоль (В хроме к примеру f12) Данный вид просмотра выполняемых данных доступен в любом браузере.
        }).catch(function(error){ // Отлавливаем ошибки, если они есть.
        console.log(error); // Так же выводим их в консоль.
        });
    })
</script>
```

Чуть подробнее о том, что делает данный код постарался расписать в комментариях.

Второй файл (Который получает данные и их обрабатывает).
Как мы уже видели ранее - называется он `form.php`. 
Это тот файл, который при получении данных через `fetch` обрабатывает их и возвращает выводимый результат.

```php
<?php
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; // Получаем данные, сформированные через fetch
print_r($_POST); // Для демонстрации выводим их на экран.(Можно скрыть данный параметр).
// Далее чтобы проверить сохранение этих данных и то, что они обрабатываются корректно, мы сохраняем их в файл. 
$file = 'text.txt'; // Указываем название файла. (Если файл лежит в другое директории, то указываем путь к файлу.
$current = file_get_contents($file); // Получаем данные из файла при необходимости
file_put_contents($file, $_POST); // Сохраняем полученные из `fetch` данные в файл
```

Теперь постараюсь показать каким образом это функционирует:
Наш первый файл:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй файл с названием `form.php`, в котором мы получаем и обрабатываем данные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример ввода данных в форму `php`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем, чтобы убедиться, что данные получены и сохранены корректно, мы можем посмотреть наш файл `txt`. (Необходимо уточнить, что Вы можете не сохранять данные в текстовый файл, это сделано исключительно для демонстрации, а обрабатывать их необходимым образом и возвращать в качестве ответа в `response` в основном Вашем файле)

Файл `txt` после записи данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В случае, если Вы всё сделали корректно, то данные у Вас успешно запишутся в файл, что Вы сможете воочию наблюдать. 
В остальном - Вы можете использовать `fetch` в практически в любых видах передачи данных, которые Вам необходимы.

Удачи Вам в Вашем проекте.

Comment: спасибо, со всем разобрался, 2 дня ломать голову из-за того, что константа ROOT не определена в этих файлах, она определена совершенно в другом месте проекта. За ваш ответ спасибо, много подчеркнул для себя, напишите мне в телеге, я же не съем вас, просто бывает что ппц тупишь и срочно нужен "взгляд извне" , спасибо ещё раз)

Comment: @Ami Kawa Я рад, что у Вас всё получилось ) Подскажите, как Вас можно в телеграмме найти?